# jEditable Conflict with bootstrap editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jeditable

```
// using jEditable
$('.element').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');


//using bootstrap editable
$('.element').editable({
                       type:  'text',
                       pk:    1,
                       name:  'username',
                       url:   'post.php',  
                       title: 'Enter username'
                    });
```

I want to use both editable plugin but I know they will conflict.. Any solution to this problem??? Thanks very...

Comment: same problem, how did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Fork jEditable and change the name of the `editable()` method in your fork. Then include that rather than the original jEditable.